# Android Studio: Bitmap to ImageView Error

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, imageview, drawable

I have a problem when attaching my Bitmap to an ImageView. This is the error I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: accelerometer.example.com.accgame, PID: 25897
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

I know it is a null pointer exception but I have no idea why getResources() returns null...
Here is my constructor class:

```
public SimulationView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mXOrigin = 50;
    mYOrigin = 50;

    mHorizontalBound = 100;
    mVerticalBound = 100;

    //Sensor Manager
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
    iBall.setImageBitmap(ball);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE, true);
    Bitmap basket = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.basket);
    mBasket = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(basket, BASKET_SIZE, BASKET_SIZE, true);
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inDither = true;
    opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    mField = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.field, opts);

    WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
}
```

Basically the error highlights the line `iBall.setImageBitmap(ball);`

In terms of the image itself, I made sure to place it in the drawables folder. It is a .jpg file and I have shrunk it by a lot as well.

Comment: Please try using context.getResources() instead of just getResources()..

Comment: Hello, unfortunately that did not work... In my main activity(which just extends AppCompatActivity) I am calling my SimulationView by the following code: SimulationView view = view = new SimulationView(this)... is that what I am supposed to pass?

Comment: `iBall` is null, regarding to error message. Try to find out, why, that will be the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize iBall in OnCreate() method

```
iBall = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```